# copy a file and get location of file at same time VBS

Tags: file, vbscript, get, copy, location

I can copy, but I don't know what to put for getting the current directory so it doesn't matter where the file is but it copies it. The code would be something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\John\Foldar\output.vbs"
Const SourceFile = "fso.BuildPath (strFolder, "getty.vbs")"

    If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\John\AnyFile\", True
        Else
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\John\AnyFile\", True
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\John\AnyFile\", True
    End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

What I need is like:

```
Const SourceFile = "currentplace\something.vbs"
```

Or something like that. Because I get the error Expected end of statement at line 4 char 48.

Here is my updated code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = fso.GetFolder(".").Path
DestinationFile = "C:\Test\getty.vbs"
SourceFile = fso.BuildPath(dir, getty.vbs)

    If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
        If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Test\", True
        Else 
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Test\", True
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
        End If
    Else
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Test\", True
    End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Use `""` (two double-quotes) to put a double-quote in a string. e.g.: `const str = "abc ""ijk"" xyz"`

Comment: It does work. The error is likely elsewhere.

Comment: I want to know what the code is in this case to get the directory of a file (where the current script is running from) so i can copy it from there.

Comment: Use `fso.GetFolder(".")` of `Scripting.FileSystemObject` before anything that changes the current directory.

Comment: where would the file name go? in between the two double quotes? or somewhere else because i put it in the double quotes and i get the error expected end of statement

Answer (score 0):

`GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)` returns the name of the folder that contains the script interpreter. That may or may not be the current working directory. If you need the working directory, do *not* use this method.

There are several ways to determine the actual working directory. One method was already proposed by @Jay:

```
strFolder = fso.GetFolder(".").Path
```

Others would be

```
strFolder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

or the [`CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method of th [`WshShell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object

```
strFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

**Edit:** As for the error you get, `Const` only works with literals, i.e. you cannot do something like

```
Const foo = fso.BuildPath(dir, filename)
```

or even something like

```
Const foo = 23 + 42
```

No calculations, no function/method calls, no string concatenation, nothing. Only literal constants:

```
Const foo = "something"
Const bar = 23
```

If you want to assign the result of a method call, you **must** use a variable:

```
foo = fso.BuildPath(dir, filename)
```

Comment: I got 'expected literal constant'

Comment: could you please specify the full code that would be used with what you are saying? like the filename goes where

Comment: I did see the updated answer, and that's what I was commenting on

Comment: That's kinda hard to believe considering that I updated the answer *after* you posted the comment.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Updated my answer again.

Comment: How do I get the directory name, like foo = fso.BuildPath(codeforgetdirhere, ialreadyknowhowtoputthishere.vbs)

Comment: In your code you use `fso.BuildPath(strFolder, "...")`. Now, where in my answer do I have code that assigns a value to a variable `strFolder`?

Comment: strFolder = fso.GetFolder(".").Path

Comment: But what do I put in the "..."

Comment: You keep that part of the original code unchanged, obviously (i.e. leave the "getty.vbs" as it is). And remove the double quotes around the `"fso.GetFolder (strFoldr, "getty.vbs")"`. you want the return value of the method, not a (broken) string "fso.GetFolder (strFoldr, "getty.vbs")". Seriously, do some of your homework yourself. This is not the right place to explain VBScript basics to you.

Comment: Well I couldn't find anyone having this anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: I get 'expected literal constant' again.

Comment: I told you to remove the `Const` keyword from that line already. After you fixed that: go read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: I'd say it's about time you updated your question with the current version of the script. I'm not going to guess which line might be giving you the error.

Comment: Updated. See if you can find it.

Comment: I told you to remove the **outer** double quotes from `"fso.GetFolder (strFoldr, "getty.vbs")"`. Why did you also remove the double quotes fromt the string `"getty.vbs"`? Without the double quotes, `getty.vbs` would be treated as the call of a method or property `vbs` on an object variable `getty`. Which is obviously wrong.